# How to create CarbonPeriod without knowing end date?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I need help with CarbonPeriod. I'm creating reminder to take medicine from one date to another in hours interval like this:

```
   $startDate = Carbon::parse($this->data->get('date'))->setTimezone($timezone);
   $endDate = Carbon::parse($this->data->get('endDate'))->addDay()->setTimezone($timezone);
   $interval = $this->data->get('interval');
   $period = new DatePeriod($startDate, CarbonInterval::hours($interval), $endDate);
```

but now I need to create CarbonPeriod knowing only $startDate and $interval in days and not the $endDate. Like I want to take my tablet every day in 12 o'clock until I turn off this reminder myself. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```php
$date = Carbon::now();
$period = $date->toPeriod(null, 3, 'days');
$period->setRecurrences(INF);
```

This will create a never-ending period that jumps 3 days at a time.

Examples directly from the documentation:

```php
CarbonPeriod::create('now', '2 days', INF); // infinite iteration
CarbonPeriod::create('now', '2 days', INF)->calculateEnd()->isEndOfTime(); // true
CarbonPeriod::create('now', CarbonInterval::days(-2), INF)->calculateEnd()->isStartOfTime(); // true
```

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period

Answer (score 0):

Typically when doing this, I would simply set the end date a very long way in the future (10 years or 20 years or 30 years ... you get the idea) and also (if you think it will ever get close to that date) have a mechanism when checking the date to extend it when it gets close (i.e. a rolling end date as such).